# Position of builtInZoomControls in WebView and MapView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-maps, android-webview

I noticed that the position of the builtInZoomControls in WebView (bottom, horizontal right) is not consistent with the default position in the MapView (bottom, horizontal center).

1) Why is that not consistent? (Probably a question to be asked to Google)

2) Is there a way to horizontal center the builtInZoomControls of the WebView without applying custom Zoom controls? Or is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with the Android UI, here's what i've noticed

1. When using a Maps activity, there is really no reason to align to the right, you are looking at a map, ie. a 2D surface that can be scrolled at will.

When browsing a website, most content starts at the left and runs right.

So, placing the control in the lower right while browsing the web makes a lot of sense, to keep it out of the way, when using maps (where the zoom control is more important), the control should be more prominent, thus in the center, where it still does not get in the way here.

2. Upon first reading your post, I was going to suggest using a custom zoom control, but I realize that you have thought about this already. If having centered controls is essential to your application, a custom control seems to be the route I'd take.

Comment: I already mentioned custom zoom control as alternative, but I'm explicitly looking for a way to apply it to the builtInZoomControls.
Obviously centering the control is essential in my case, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question.
(Sorry, not really helpful answer.. or at least nothing new in there.)

Comment: "When browsing a website, most content starts at the left and runs right." - for Western cultures it's true, for others it might not. But I guess it's just a typical case of Google's inability to design consistent UIs, they've always been good on failing at this.

Answer (score 0):

When viewing maps in a WebView you are actually using the Browser app to view the Map Tiles. In order to change the zoom controls when in Web View you would have to manipulate the zoom controls of the browser being used to view the Map Tiles.

You should try manipulating the WebView zoom controls and not the MapView zoom controls.

Comment: I'm not using maps in a WebView, I'm using a MapView. I just want the zoom controls to be consistent in both view components, web view and map view, without applying custom controls. The map view and web view in my app are not related to each other, I just want their zoom controls to be consistent - but without having to use custom zoom controls, that's just inconvenient.